# Implementing SkipListener to write invalid records to a flat file

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on setting a spring batch job that does the conventional READ > PROCESS > WRITE operation.  However, I am trying to implement a listener which would capture records that are conisdered invalid during the PROCESS phase and write it out to an error log file.

My listener class uses an instance of FlatFileItemWriter to write the data.  However, spring-batch is not instantiating the writer instance properly.

My listener class looks like this:

```
    public class DTOProcessorListener extends SkipListenerSupport<AttributeReportGenerationDTO, AttributeValue> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DTOProcessorListener.class);

    private FlatFileItemWriter<AttributeReportGenerationDTO> flatFileItemWriter;

    @Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(AttributeReportGenerationDTO item, Throwable t) {

        try {
            LOGGER.error("Record not processed for attribute value with ID : " + item.getAttributeValueId());
            List<AttributeReportGenerationDTO> list = new ArrayList<AttributeReportGenerationDTO>();
            list.add(item);
            flatFileItemWriter.write(list);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to write to the error output file", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param flatFileItemWriter
     *            the flatFileItemWriter to set
     */
    public void setFlatFileItemWriter(FlatFileItemWriter<AttributeReportGenerationDTO> flatFileItemWriter) {

        this.flatFileItemWriter = flatFileItemWriter;
    }

}
```

and my job configuration XML looks like this:

```
<bean id="skipListener" class="something.DTOProcessorListener" scope="step">
        <property name="flatFileItemWriter">
            <bean id="errorItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
                <property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['error.filename']}" />
                <property name="appendAllowed" value="true" />
                <property name="lineAggregator">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                        <property name="fieldExtractor">
                            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                                <property name="names"
                                    value="productTypeId, productTypeName, productId, productName, skuId, skuName, attributeValueId, attributeName, attributeValue, attributeType, nonEditableValueCheckSum, editableValueCheckSum" />
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="headerCallback">
                    <bean class="something.CsvHeaderImplementation">
                        <property name="headerString"
                            value="Product Type ID,Product Type,Product ID,Product Name,Sku ID,Sku Name,Attribute Value ID,Attribute Name,Attribute Value,Attribute Type,Check Sum 1,Check Sum 2" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I get the error

```
org.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open before it can be written to
```

I am unable to set a stream entry in the job config as the bean for FlatFileItemWriter is internally specified (for the listener).  If I create abean outside of the listener and refer to it, its returning a proxy instance of the FlatFileItemWriterClass.

Has anyone successfully wired up a writer to a flat file in the listener?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well why don't you use the writer as a normal bean ? You could [register it as a stream](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#registeringItemStreams) and to get around the step proxy you could use the [PropertPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)

i created a working example under [my github repo](https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch-examples-listeners/blob/master/src/main/resources/spring/batch/job/listeners/listener-with-file-output-job.xml), but i think spring batch could need an improvement here, it should be easier to implement error-item logging

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.  I was wondering if you could explain as to how I could use the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to wire up the writer to the listerner bean.  I thought the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer was for wiring up property files.

Comment: the PPC is for the jobParameter not for wiring up the beans, so you get the error.filename properly replaced

Comment: Michael, error.filename is getting picked up properly in the current configuration.  Its just that when an instance of flatfileitemwriter is getting set on my listener class, its creating a proxy instance.  Are you suggesting that your solution would solve the problem I am having?

Comment: to bypass the (stepscoped) proxy i would go with the normal bean configuration

Comment: this is what I did... if i create the writer bean externally and refer to it in the listener class, spring batch is creating a proxied instance of the writer class.. if i create the writer bean as an inner bean of the listener class, the  I am unable to refer to it as a stream in batch:chunk section... and hence I get the "Writer must be open before it can be written to" error.. not making progress as a result of it..

Comment: thats great... thanks a lot... i am now able to write to the error file although i would like a new error file (different filename) to be created every time the job is run and hence a property config file wouldnt work.. are you aware of how one can get hold of the job instance id in the xml file so that i can use that value to suffix the file name?

Comment: maybe you can alter this example https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch-examples/wiki/Rename-Files ? create the error file with timestamp, rename it afterwards (like shown in example), get job instance id in job listener (jobExecution has a getId)